# How to return 404 error in Scrapy when I don't want to handle all 404 errors?

Tags: web-scraping, error-handling, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to handle 404 errors in Scrapy, but not all 404 error cases. How can I raise a 404 error when I don't want to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it turns out I can handle 404 response from a specific request using `errback`.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror import HttpError

class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sample'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    start_urls = ["https://example.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        if response.status in self.handle_httpstatus_list:
            return Request(url="https://example.com/404url/", callback=self.parse_page, errback=self.after_404)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        # parse the page and extract items for success result

    def after_404(self, failure):
        if failure.check(HttpError) and failure.value.response.status == 404:
            print ("We got 404!")

            # handle the page for 404 status
        else: 
            # Log others as error
            self.logger.error(repr(failure))
```

This way, other requests that I don't want it to handle 404 status still return the errors as usual.

I made it based on https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-errbacks